# How to check if a substring in a pandas dataframe column exists in a substring of another column in the same dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, string-matching

I have a dataframe with columns like this:

```
  A                               B
0  - 5923FoxRd                    5923 Fox Rd
1 631 Newhaven Ave                Modesto
2 Saratoga Street, Suite 200      Saratoga Street, Suite 200
```

I want to create a list with values from A that matches values from B. The list should look like [- 5923FoxRd, Saratoga Street, Suite 200...]. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Why is row 0 a match?

Comment: Thats because the address is the same in both the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a little go a long way, do the following:

1. Create a new series for each column and pass the regex pattern `\W+` to `str.replace()`
2. use `str.lower()`
3. create replace lists to normalize `drive` to `dr`, `avenue` to `ave`, etc.

---

```
s1 = df['A'].str.replace('\W+', '').str.lower()
s2 = df['B'].str.replace('\W+', '').str.lower()
lst = [*df[s1==s2]['A']]
lst
Out[1]: ['- 5923FoxRd', 'Saratoga Street, Suite 200']
```

This is what `s1` and `s2` look like:

```
print(s1,s2)

0                 5923foxrd
1            631newhavenave
2    saratogastreetsuite200
Name: A, dtype: object

0                 5923foxrd
1                   modesto
2    saratogastreetsuite200
Name: B, dtype: object
```

---

From there, you might want to create some replace values in order to normalize your data even further like:

```
to_replace = ['drive', 'avenue', 'street']
replaced = ['dr', 'ave', 'str']

to_replace = ['drive', 'avenue', 'street']
replaced = ['dr', 'ave', 'str']
s1 = df['A'].str.replace('\W+', '').str.lower().replace(to_replace, replaced, regex=True)
s2 = df['B'].str.replace('\W+', '').str.lower().replace(to_replace, replaced, regex=True)
lst = [*df[s1==s2]['A']]
lst
print(s1,s2)
0              5923foxrd
1         631newhavenave
2    saratogastrsuite200
Name: A, dtype: object

0              5923foxrd
1                modesto
2    saratogastrsuite200
Name: B, dtype: object
```